# Add @Schedule annotation using AOP in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, aop, ejb-3.1, schedule

I am trying to create schedule event using EJB 3.1 @Schedule annotation. Everything works fine as long as I have the annotation inside my bean. Because I want to be able to change schedule in deploy time without repacking ear I want to add this annotation using AOP. But this does not work.

Here is my sample bean:

```
@AspectDomain(value = "TimerBeanDomain")
@Singleton
public class TimerBean {

    public void timerMethod() {
        System.out.println("Timer method activated");
    }

}
```

Here is my aop.xml file (packed outside -ejb.jar):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<aop xmlns="urn:jboss:aop-beans:1.0">
    <domain name="TimerBeanDomain">
        <annotation expr="method(void *->timerMethod(..))">
            @javax.ejb.Schedule(second = "*/30", minute = "*", hour = "*")
        </annotation>
    </domain>
</aop>
```

Bean is packed inside -ejb.jar and aop file is outside this -ejb.jar.

There are no errors in console. It just does not work.

I tried it with stateless bean as well. But it does not help. In this case aop.xml looked like

```
<domain name="TimerBeanDomain" extends="Stateless Bean" inheritBindings="true">
```

I am using Jboss 6.0.1 and 6.1.0. At least is there some way how to debug the AOP process of adding annotation?

Any help will be appreciate.

Regards, Eman

Answer (score 1):

You can still configure the schedule outside of the code with EJB3.1, without using AOP, see:

[Can the EJB 3.1 @Schedule be configured outside of the application code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950636/can-the-ejb-3-1-schedule-be-configured-outside-of-the-application-code?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's a known bug: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/EJBTHREE-1632

I shall look into the matter in a bit more detail during forthcoming weekends & let you know if I find any work-around.