# Possible to change ejb parameter at runtime for @Schedule annotation?

Tags: java, timer, glassfish, ejb-3.1, schedule

Probably a silly question for someone with ejb experience...

I want to read and change the minute parameter dynamically for one of my EJB beans that uses the Java EE scheduler via the `@Schedule` annotation. Anyone know how to do this at runtime as opposed to hardcoding it in the class like below? If i were to do it programatically could i still use the `@Schedule` annotation?

```
 @Schedule(dayOfWeek = "0-5", hour = "0/2", minute = "0/20", timezone = "America/Los_Angeles")
 private void checkInventory() {
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the EJB 3.1 @Schedule be configured outside of the application code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950636/can-the-ejb-3-1-schedule-be-configured-outside-of-the-application-code)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`@Schedule` is for automatic timers created by the container during deployment.

On the other hand, you can use [`TimerService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html) which allows you to define at runtime when the `@Timeout` method should be called.

This might be interesting material for your: [The Java EE 6 Tutorial - Using the Timer Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html).

**EDIT:** Just to make this answer more complete. If it's a matter of *is it possible* than the answer would be - *yes, it is.*

There is a way to "change the parameters" of automatic timer created with `@Schedule`. Nevertheless it's quite **extraordinary** - it cancels the automatic timer and creates a similar programmatic one:

```
// Automatic timer - run every 5 seconds
// It's a automatic (@Schedule) and programmatic (@Timeout) timer timeout method
// at the same time (which is UNUSUAL)
@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/5")
@Timeout
public void myScheduler(Timer timer) {

    // This might be checked basing on i.e. timer.getInfo().
    firstSchedule = ...

    if (!firstSchedule) {
        // ordinary code for the scheduler
    } else {

        // Get actual schedule expression.
        // It's the first invocation, so it's equal to the one in @Schedule(...)
        ScheduleExpression expr = timer.getSchedule();

        // Your new expression from now on
        expr.second("*/7");

        // timers is TimerService object injected using @Resource TimerService.

        // Create new timer based on modified expression.
        timers.createCalendarTimer(expr);

        // Cancel the timer created with @Schedule annotation.
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

Once again - personally, I would never use such code and would never want to see anything like this in a real project :-) Either the timer is:

- **automatic** and is created by `@Schedule` by hard-coding the values or by defining them in ejb-jar.xml,
- **programmatic** and is created by the application code which can have different values in the runtime.

Comment: So do we need to send Timer as argument for the first time?